# Directory.CreateDirectory on a network path

Tags: c#, network-programming

I'm trying to create a new directory tree on a network path.

The share is located at `\\192.168.5.193\FileContext` and has `Everyone` **full access** permissions.

This piece of code:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = Directory.
  CreateDirectory(@"\\192.168.5.193\FileContext\FileContext_Root\General\Test");
```

gives me:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

If I try to open the same address with Windows Explorer, it opens up without password requirements.

The `CreateDirectory()` documentation states it should accept UNC paths:

> You can create a directory on a remote computer, on a share that you have write access to. UNC paths are supported; for example, you can specify the following for path: \2009\Archives\December in Visual Basic, and \\2009\Archives\December in C#.

It also states that `IOException`s could came from:

> The directory specified by path is a file .
>   -or-
>   The network name is not known.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/54a0at6s(v=vs.100).aspx

How can I resolve?

Comment: Is the code _definitely_ running in the same user context as you're doing with Explorer?  It's not a website etc?

Comment: Is this code running in a Windows Service under different credentials from your Windows user? IIS runs as a service...

Comment: It's an IIS website. But the share is accessible to `Everyone` as I wrote.

Comment: [Everyone isn't Everyone](https://weaselfire.wordpress.com/2009/07/09/everyone-isnt-everyone/)

Comment: Share permissions aren't the only permissions that matter. You may want to show a bit more cooperation and information.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I'm reading

Comment: @CodeCaster That folder has also all read/write permissions possible.

Comment: And yet it doesn't work, so please just add all relevant information to your question and try doing some research. You can have two questions: either _"How can I make a share writable without having to log in to the server"_, or _"How to log in to a share from a Windows Service"_. Both questions have been asked before.

Comment: @CodeCaster I think the solution is in the James' comment.

Comment: I hope you don't think the answer is to add NETWORK SERVICE to the Everyone group.

Comment: @CodeCaster Nope.  Just create a new group - ["Everyone and their dog"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/everyone_and_their_dog).  Start by populating it with Everyone and Network Service, then go from there...

Comment: @James tongue-in-cheek I hope...

Comment: @CodeCaster Of course :)

Comment: The only problem is that I cannot add my computer NETWORK SERVICE to the share's permissions because the share's computer is not on my domain.

Comment: So I requested to my Sys Admin to add that VM to the domain

Comment: Just by adding the VM to the domain, I solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from @JamesThorpe comment:

> [Everyone isn't Everyone](https://weaselfire.wordpress.com/2009/07/09/everyone-isnt-everyone/)

I came to the solution, just by adding the remote computer to the company domain.

With this action, it's not even necessary to add local computer's `NETWORK SERVICE` to remote folder's permissions.