# username or password is incorrect

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So the error that I'm facing is that the error keep happening when I tried to run it on web server but not on localhost
the error happen most likely because of the web server don't have the required permission to create directory on the file server .

```
 Dim folderPath As String = ("\\172.xx.x.xx\foldername\)
 Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
```

the create directory work fine in localhost but not on web server.I've tried to go file properties>sharing>add evryone >check full control so that the user will have permisison to read and write on the folder but the same error keep showing.

Is there any other suggestion that I can apply to fix the error?

Comment: What error do you get? The web server and the `172.xx.x.xx` are on same network?

Comment: ye on the same network. the error that I got is  ' username or password is incorrect' which I assume that I do not have the permission to create directory .

Comment: What is the user identity under which the application pool is running on the server? That will be used by the application to perform any IO operations. You need to use proper user identity which has privileges.

Comment: Maybe the server in question in not part of the company's domain? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883171/directory-createdirectory-on-a-network-path

Comment: When you run on localhost, the webapp (probably) runs under *your* account, so it is *you* that is creating that directory. On the webserver it is (probably) running as some local user with restricted permissions that is not allowed to create folders on that other (?) server